# Type or namespace ExcelDataReader could not be found - but everything compiles and runs ok

Tags: c#, exceldatareader

VS2017 C#

I am getting the above  error, crazy thing is, everything compiles and runs and the ExcelData Reader is working fine!
I updated the package using the Manage->Nuget.. but still showing the error..

Comment: To get the obvious out of the way: did you restart VS?

Comment: I have restarted it... many times and also rebooted the computer. I am just ignoring it for now!

Comment: Please include a screenshot of the error.

Comment: If it compiles and it runs, I'm confused to the nature of the error. Is this at compile-time? Also, do you know when did this come up first, after VS upgrading or something? or did it just pop out of the blue.

Comment: When I do a clean solution it disappears. When I build / run, it reappears. It looks like a VS bug of some kind as it isn't prevented the build at all.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated to this package using Manage->NuGet
'ExcelDataReader.DataSet.3.4.0

The rogue error has magically disappeared